# Embedded Adobe Acrobat PDF stealing focus

Tags: asp.net, pdf, activex, acrobat

I am embedding Adobe Acrobat in our c# program by inheriting AxHost and passing in the Acrobat `guid("ca8a9780-280d-11cf-a24d-444553540000")` to the base constructor. To load a pdf I call `InvokeMember("LoadFile")`. The problem I am running into is after calling "LoadFile" and the PDF loads, Acrobat takes the focus in our form. Being Acrobat apparently starts loading on another thread, calling focus on the control that previously had focus, doesn't fix the problem. So does anyone have any idea of how I can prevent this from occurring?

Comment: I posted a possible solution here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074857/axacropdf-swallowing-keys-how-to-get-it-to-stop/21159725#21159725

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet.......

```
        this.Refresh();
        axAcroPDF1.Focus();
        axAcroPDF1.SendToBack();

        **AnyControl**.Focus();
        this.Refresh();
```