# .net PDF Viewer control

Tags: .net, pdf, pdf-viewer

We are looking for a PDF Viewer control for WPF or WinForms application.

We have hit some road blocks with our current implementation which basically uses WindowsFormsHost to embed the Adobe Reader activeX control inside a WPF UserControl.

Using the above implementation we cannot do the following:

- Consistently show rotate buttons
- Save the file (We can save a copy, but not re-save) so we can keep the rotation that the user just performed.

I've scoured the internet for a .net control that has no external dependencies and found [this component created by wpcubed](http://www.wpcubed.com/products/pdfviewer/index.htm) and I've played with it and it seems to meet our needs. My question is are there some other alternatives?

If there are some LGPL-like licensed open source, we could consider it, but most likely we want to go with a 3rd party component preferably with a royalty-free distribution. But I'm just looking for some options that I haven't found  yet.

Answer (score 10):

[Here](http://paul-usher.com/2012/09/10/net-pdf-viewer-showdown/) is a great article detailing some contenders.

- Gnostice (www.gnostice.com)
- Atalasoft (www.atalasoft.com)
- DynamicPDF (www.dynamicpdf.com)
- Aspose (www.aspose.com)
- ActivePDF (www.activepdf.com)
- Deaja (www.daeja.com)
- Snowbound Software (snowbound.com)
- Bluebeam Q (www.bluebeam.com)
- PDFTron (www.pdftron.com)
- GDPicture (www.gdpicture.com)
- SyncFusion (www.syncfusion.com)
- O2 Solutions (www.o2sol.com)

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Comment: It is good to have a list of the latest PDF viewers for .NET in one place.  It could save some people a lot of Google searching.

Comment: I find this post very informative.  Some of these options are hard to find on Google.

Answer (score 3):

[PDFView4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm) lets you display PDF files in WinForms and WPF applications. It includes support for rotating pages and saving the PDF file. [PDFView4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm) comes with royalty free distribution.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops PDFView4NET.

Comment: it doesn't have any external dependencies, i.e. does it need Adobe Reader to run?

Comment: @Jose - no dependencies on Adobe software or other software, a single assembly to include in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Some other components

Component One 
http://www.componentsource.com/news/2010/11/18/componentone-studio-wpf.html)
http://www.componentsource.com/products/expertpdf-pdf-viewer/summary.html

DevXpress
http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Printing/

Try the answer to this question (it has an interesting blog link - which I have added below)
[Please suggest a PDF viewer for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495276/please-suggest-a-pdf-viewer-for-wpf)

Article may be of use
http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/