# WPF XAML compile error- the name does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to add the capability to view a PDF file from within my WPF application.

I have been following the tutorial at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/579878/MoonPdfPanel-A-WPF-based-PDF-Viewer-Control#include, and am at the section titled "Including MoonPdfPanel in your Application".

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DocumentViewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DocumentViewer"
    xmlns:mpp="DocumentViewer:MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <DockPanel>
    <mpp:MoonPdfPanel Background="LightGray" ViewType="SinglePage" PageDisplay="ContinuousPages" PageMargin="0,2,4,2" AllowDrop="True"/>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Menu x:Name="menu" IsMainMenu="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="518">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem x:Name="loadDocument" Header="Load Document" Click="openFileMenuItem_click"></MenuItem>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem x:Name="exit" Header="Exit" Click="exitApplication_click"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="browserHost" DockPanel.Dock="Top"   Margin="0,0,0,0">
    </Grid>
    <!--mpp:MoonPdfPanel x:Name="PdfPanel" Background="LightGray" ViewType="SinglePage" PageMargin="0,2,4,2" AllowDrop="True" /-->
    <!--mpp:MoonPdfPanel Background="LightGray" ViewType="SinglePage" PageDisplay="ContinuousPages" PageMargin="0,2,4,2" AllowDrop="True"/-->


  </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

However, for some reason, I am getting a compile error on the line:

```
        <mpp:MoonPdfPanel Background="LightGray" ViewType="SinglePage" PageDisplay="ContinuousPages" PageMargin="0,2,4,2" AllowDrop="True"/>
```

which says:

> The name "MoonPdfPanel" does not exist in the namespace "DocumentViewer:MoonPdfLib

I downloaded the MoonPdfViewer from https://sourceforge.net/projects/moonpdf/?source=typ_redirect, and have ensured that it is in the root of my workspace... as far as I can tell, I have followed everything the tutorial says to do, and yet I am getting this compile error...

If I try to run the application, when it tells me that there were build errors, and asks if I would like to continue and run the last successful build, if I say 'No', 3 errors are shown in the console:

> The name "MoonPdfPanel" does not exist in the namespace "DocumentViewer:MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib".
>
> The property 'PageDisplay' was not found in the type 'MoonPdfPanel'.
>
> The property 'PageDisplay' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib'. Line 11 Position 72.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I add this `MoonPdfPanel` to my application?

Comment: Your namespace says `DocumentViewer:MoonPdfLib`. It should be just `MoonPdfLib` -- `clr-namespace:MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib`

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work, so I tried adding the line `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DocumentViewer"` and then using `xmlns:mpp="DocumentViewer:MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib"`, but I'm still having trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at your code and the link you provided, your namespace is wrong.

You have:

```
xmlns:mpp="DocumentViewer:MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib"
```

It should be:

```
xmlns:mpp="clr-namespace:MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib"
```

Your local namespace may be `DocumentViewer`, but namespaces for 3rd party libraries use the project references. So, you don't include your namespace unless it's an actual component in your namespace, such as your own custom control. Even then, the namespace is delimited with a period, `.`, not a colon.

The panel is added as such:

```
<mpp:MoonPdfPanel Name="pdfPanel" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="LightGray" 
    ViewType="SinglePage" PageRowDisplay="ContinuousPageRows" PageMargin="0,2,4,2" AllowDrop="True"/>
```

I was able to load a PDF without any problems using:

```
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.Title = "Select a PDF File";
     ofd.Filter = "PDF File (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
     if ((bool)ofd.ShowDialog())
     {
        pdfPanel.OpenFile(ofd.FileName);
     }
```

The result looked like this:

[image: MoonPdf Display]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer- I've given that a go, and it has removed one of the compile errors I was getting (one that said `The property 'PageDisplay' was not found in type 'MoonPdfPanel'`). However, I still get the compile error that says: `The type 'mpp:MoonPdfPanel' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`

Comment: I'll see if I can give it a quick test myself. There's probably something simple missing.

Comment: @someone2088 I fixed the namespace. I was missing the prefix (doh!). Also, `PageDisplay` isn't a member of the panel. The closest thing I found was `PageRowDisplay`, so I created a sample line for that. You can see all of the available properties, events, etc, by looking at it in the Object Browser under `MoonPdfLib -> {} MoonPdfLib -> MoonPdfPanel`

Comment: Thanks for update, this was something I had already tried- although I can build my code, `<mpp:MoonPdfPanel` is still underlined (the warning displays message `The name "MoonPdfPanel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib".`. When I try running the application, it breaks, telling me that a "XamlParseException has occurred". The InnerException for this says: `{"Could not load file or assembly 'MoonPdfLib, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."}`

Comment: @someone2088 I'm not having that problem. I edited my answer to show what mine is doing. This was done in VS2015 with .NET 4.6. Note: I have explicitly set my build to x86, and I'm using the x86 libraries.

Comment: Ah- think I've fixed it now... it seems that the `MoonPdfLib-x86` that I had tried installing from the NuGet packages hadn't actually been installed... there were two options there- the one I had tried didn't install for some reason, but I've now tried the other one and that has installed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I had just downloaded the Sourceforge binaries and extracted them to a folder. :-)