# AcroPDF VBA Tabstop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Textbox1, Label1 and a AcroPDF1. My goal is to use a barcode scanner and scan a material number. I don't have keybord or mouse available at that location. The barcode scanner gives a Enter asci at the end. That is fine but it makes it go to the next index. I tried everything not to jump to the AcroPDF but the Tabstop is already on false but it still jumps into the PDF. So I want to be able to scan at any time and a special pdf beeing displayed.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 13 Then
        If InStr(TextBox1.Value, "_") <> 0 Then
            TextBox1.Value = Left(TextBox1.Value, InStrRev(TextBox1.Value, "_", , vbTextCompare) - 1)
        End If
    Label1.Caption = TextBox1.Value
    TextBox1.Value = ""
    AcroPDF1.LoadFile "F:\APPS\Packaging\84260388.pdf"
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I'm reading this correctly, but once the PDF is loaded you want to set focus back to the textbox?  If thats the case, use the `TextBox1.SetFocus()` Method after your PDF Load.  That will set the cursor back to the textbox.

Comment: I tried that before. It will not go back to TextBox1. It is still with the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

it is indeed not very clear how to set focus back to the form after activating axAcroPDF control. this problem is discussed in threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074857/axacropdf-swallowing-keys-how-to-get-it-to-stop). there are 3 solutions offered, but they seem to me more like hacks, because axAcroPDF ActiveX control has in itself a rather unusual behavior. i am afraid that (finally) using this control with a complex and/or serious application is not a good idea.

Comment: i myself finally used the Timer hack to return focus once the control has been activated. the thing in my case is that, even though the control seems to have a strange behaviour, it's still the fastest solution to display PDFs - the time to convert PDF to a GDI+ manageable image is quite significant (i used ImageMagick COM+ component)